# 3D Map - Where do the “Fields” come from?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to test out the new 3d map feature in Excel, but can't figure where they're getting the field name categories:

[image]

I have only one table, and it's called "World_Storage", which isn't obviously a choice. Even going to the named ranges, I only see my "World_Storage" table.  Where is it finding `Table1` and `Table2`, and what is `Range`?

I also can't find a way to work "backwards" and find where these are.  Any advice would be most appreciated!